# Python API SqLite Request

Tags: python, sqlite, api

Коллеги через API нужно узнать данные о стране. Скрипт написал. strana=input('Vvedite stranu korotko:'). Просто напишите RU. Скрипт работает,но когда активирую скрипт (INSERT) чтобы записывал на BD то идет ошибка

```
import requests  
import sqlite3 as sql

db = sql.connect('country_info.db')
cursor = db.cursor()

# cursor.executescript('''
# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS country_info;
#
# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (
#     country_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
#     Country TEXT,
#     Region TEXT,
#     Location INTEGER,
#     Phone_code INTEGER,
#     Capital TEXT
# );
# ''')

headers = {
  'X-CSCAPI-KEY': 'ZngzTUM1RkpiQ0w0Y0FDZHh3VG45YnNWdEVTTzVIUDZ6SHg2dmI2ZQ=='
}

while True:
    try:
        strana=input('Vvedite stranu korotko:')
        req = requests.get(f"https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/{strana}", headers=headers)
        posts = req.json()

        Country_name=posts['name']
        Region=posts['region']
        Location_lat=posts['latitude']
        Location_long=posts['longitude']
        Location= (Location_lat, Location_long)
        Phone_code=posts['phonecode']
        Capital=posts['capital']

        # cursor.execute('''
        #         INSERT INTO cities (Country, Region, Location, Phone_code, Capital) VALUES
        #         (?,?,?,?,?)
        #         ''', (Country_name, Region, Location, Phone_code, Capital))
        #
        # print('Данные добавлены в базу данных!')

        print(f'''
        Страна:{Country_name},
        Регион:{Region},
        Локация: {Location},
        Код_телефона: {Phone_code},
        Столица: {Capital}''')


    except Exception as e:
        print('СТРАНА КОТОРУЮ ВЫ ЗАДАЛИ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ')
```

Comment: Ошибок может быть +100500, напишите в вопросе какая у вас :)

Comment: Добрый вечер! Когда активирую этот код то не работает:    # cursor.execute('''
        #         INSERT INTO cities (Country, Region, Location, Phone_code, Capital) VALUES
        #         (?,?,?,?,?)
        #         ''', (Country_name, Region, Location, Phone_code, Capital))
        #
        # print('Данные добавлены в базу данных!')

Comment: У вас вообще закомментирован... :) Не думаю, что из-за этого... Попробуйте явно вызывать коммит. Коммит вызывайте у коннекта, у вас этот объект в переменной `db`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/sqlite3__examples/append_image/main.py#L27